# How to use the SharePoint object model to create groups on a current site level instead of the top site level

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Is there a way to programmically create groups, roles on a current site level, instead of creating it on the top level site?

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

No. Groups are defined at the site collection level. This blog post explains the concepts of SharePoint security and more in detail:

[SharePoint Security Fundamentals Primer](http://paulgalvin.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!1CC1EDB3DAA9B8AA!398.entry?sa=951334167)